# Determining reflow oven temperature wave and best practices

Tags: surface-mount, reflow, solder-paste

I am new to reflow soldering and am wondering the general approach for determining reflow wave setpoints.  The solder paste I am using is [MG chemicals data sheet](https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/71mbq+D+Z-L.pdf) and am using several decently sensitive components such as electrolytic capacitors and MCU chips.  For example for the electrolytic capacitor the datasheet suggests a pretty different temperature peak reflow profile [capacitor datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/445/865080543009-1726610.pdf).

The two reflow profiles can be seen below.  But should one just find the most sensitive SMD component (lowest max temperature tolerance) and just cater to it? Select a solder paste that will flow below its max temp?  Are there any other criteria to ensure good SMD soldering in a reflow oven?

solder paste wave

[image: solderpaste wave]

capacitor wave

[image: capacitor]

Comment: Reflow or wave? I suspect reflow, so why the mention of wave? Or does wave = profile?

Comment: @Kartman reflow oven temperature profile